# написание НЕ при усилении ЕЩЁ

Tags: частица-не

Есть предложение:

> СЭО «Лотос» – это **еще не большая группа** ребят, объединившихся для защиты экологии.

Вопрос: НЕ пишется с прилагательным слитно. Но если я подразумеваю частицей ЕЩЕ усилить смысл и написать ЕЩЕ НЕ_БОЛЬШАЯ (имеется ввиду вовсе/совсем/совершенно не большая). Правильно ли будет написание раздельное ? Возможен ли такой вариант?

Могу ли я считать ЕЩЕ в данном контексте усилительной частицей ?

Comment: Группе ребят ни к чему защищать науку, а вот окружающую среду — актуально.

Answer (score 2):

НЕ с прилагательными пишется и так и сяк. 
Наличие "ещё" ничего не меняет.

В Вашем предложении кто же за автора решит, отрицает ли он признак (раздельно) или утверждает (слитно)? Как считаете, так и пишите. Заодно неплохо бы придушить того гада, который придумывает правила про слитное написание.

> СЭО «Лотос» – это ещё не большая группа ребят, объединившихся для
>   защиты экологии.

Всё в порядке.

---

**[Не с прилагательными (слитно и раздельно)](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/ebbc76cf-46b6-4d51-ad92-d9a84db35cfa/[I-RUS_06-03]_[TE_17-SU]/[I-RUS_06-03]_[TE_17-SU].html)**

**[Как пишется «не» с прилагательными?](http://kakimenno.ru/obrazovanie-i-nauka/srednee-obrazovanie/2025-kak-pishetsya-ne-s-prilagatelnymi.html)**

> Обратите внимание: может быть двоякое толкование.
>
> Сравните два примера.
>
> *Это не сложная задача* («…а простая», то есть вы не считаете, что задача сложная).
>
> *Это несложная задача* (вы утверждаете, что задача легкая).
>
> Сравните:
>
> *Задача не простая, а сложная.*
>
> *Задача непростая, но выполнимая* («да, задача не является простой, но, несмотря на это, ее можно выполнить»).

Далее:

> Если в качестве поясняющих слов мы видим наречия «совсем», «вовсе»,
>   они могут означать либо «очень», «совершенно», «абсолютно» (и тогда
>   выберем слитное написание «не» с прилагательным), либо «отнюдь не»
>   (выберем раздельное написание). Сравните:
>
> *Это был совсем ненужный разговор* (утверждение: «да, абсолютно ненужный»).
>
> *Это была вовсе не случайная встреча* (отрицание: «нет, отнюдь не случайная»).
>
> **Слитно или раздельно: сравнительная степень**
>
> Если перед вами сочетание частицы «не» и прилагательного в
>   сравнительной степени, нужно обратить внимание на смысл высказывания,
>   так как возможны варианты написания. Сравните:
>
> *Этот рисунок некрасивее того* («более некрасив, чем другой»).
>   *Этот рисунок не красивее того* («не является более красивым, чем другой»).

Answer (score 0):

СЭО «Лотос» – это **еще не большая** группа ребят, объединившихся для защиты экологии. Здесь отрицание, логически выделено слово с НЕ.

Сравнить: СЭО «Лотос» – это **еще одна небольшая** (маленькая) группа ребят, объединившихся для защиты экологии.

**Пояснение (общий  принцип решения)**

При наличии  в предложении наречия  ЕЩЁ встречаются  обе формы написания НЕ, **орфограмма решается по общим правилам.**

1) Утверждение

**Еще недолго** (мало времени) ждать весны.
Например: Во Вселенной существуют **еще неизвестные** элементы. В лесах **ещё нередко** можно встретить диких животных.

2) Отрицание

Это **еще не дорого**, дом был **еще не старый** – **выбор раздельной формы написания по смыслу** (на слово с частицей НЕ обычно падает интонационное ударение).

Например:  **Не старая ещё** и довольно красивая женщина внесла самовар. Демидов – странный человек, физически очень сильный, **еще не старый**, замкнутый, нелюдимый.